# Not able to fetch media:content data

Tags: php, xml, rss

```
    $rss = simplexml_load_file('URL');

    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
         $title = strip_tags($item->title); 
         $desc = strip_tags($item->description); 
    }
```

**MY XML DATA LIKE:**

```
<title> <![CDATA[ Title data here ]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[ Description here ]]> </description>

<media:group>
<media:content url="https://myurl.com/poster.jpg?width=1920" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"/>
<media:content url="https://myurl.com/videos/erer-sdfer.mp4" duration="100" width="320" height="180" fileSize="4234581" 
</media:group>
```

**In the XML above I can retrieve the title and description information, but I need to have access to the "url" property value from the media:group -> media:content node. Please assist me in locating this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements use a different namespace. Look for the `xmlns:media` namespace definition in your XML document. The value is the actual namespace. It should be `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` in this case - Media RSS.

SimpleXML uses the default namespace of the current element until you select another. The `SimpleXMLElement::children()` and `SimpleXMLElement::attributes()` methods have an argument for the namespace.

```php
// define a dictionary for the used namespaces
$xmlns = [
    'mrss' => 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
];

$rss = simplexml_load_string(getXMLString());

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   $title = strip_tags($item->title); 
   $description = strip_tags($item->description); 
   var_dump($title, $description);
   // fetch elements of the specified namespace
   foreach ($item->children($xmlns['mrss'])->group->content as $content) {
       var_dump((string)$content->attributes()->url);
   }
}

function getXMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title> <![CDATA[ Title data here ]]></title>
      <description><![CDATA[ Description here ]]> </description>
    
      <media:group>
        <media:content url="https://myurl.com/poster.jpg?width=1920" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <media:content url="https://myurl.com/videos/erer-sdfer.mp4" duration="100" width="320" height="180" fileSize="4234581"/>
      </media:group>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
XML;
}
```

Output:

```
string(18) "  Title data here "
string(19) " Description here  "
string(39) "https://myurl.com/poster.jpg?width=1920"
string(39) "https://myurl.com/videos/erer-sdfer.mp4"
```